# How to create a Method to generate a list of Accounts based on a record type of the account?

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]I am trying to create a method do pull all accounts that have a record type of REE. I have the following lines and it does not work, because all accounts come up. This is for a Visualforce Page where a field is an "Account" field with pick list values of Accounts.

```
//Method to get the Account List drop down
    public List<SelectOption>getAccountOptions() {
    ID rtAccount = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('REE').getRecordTypeId();       
        System.Debug('getAccountOptions Start');
        //Execute query to get the respective roles
        System.debug('<<<<<<< Get Account List Method Started >>>>>>>');
        

       
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
       for(Account acc: [SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeId= :rtAccount LIMIT 200]) 
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.Name));
        }
        System.debug('<<<<<<< Get Account List Method Completed >>>>>>>');
         System.Debug('getAccountOptions End');
        return options;
       
    }
```

Comment: easier would be `[SELECT .... FROM Account WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName = 'REE']`

Comment: Is it possible to create a method with If Then statement. The Account list that is displayed in the Pick list to show accouns based on the Record type selected in the other pic list. I will attach a screen shot of it.

Comment: i don't see where the Account Record Type is shown on the form - only a Contact Record Type

Answer (score 0):

Try to get recordtype by this code
Id rtAccount = Schema.sObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosbyName().get('REE').getRecordTypeId();
OR
Id rtAccount = [select Id from RecordType where Name = 'REE' and sobjecttype = 'Account'].Id;